# .NET 6 - Unable to read values from Azure App Configuration Service and map to strong-typed class object

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-6.0, azure-app-configuration

I have created the Azure App Configuration service in Azure and added some configurations there as
[image]

Then I have a .NET 6 web application where I am trying to read the configurations from the azure service and map those to an object using `IOptions` as:

**Program.cs**

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Configuration.AddAzureAppConfiguration(option =>
{
    option.Connect("myconnectionstring")
   .ConfigureRefresh(refresh =>
   {
    refresh.Register("AppSettings:Sentinel", "Development", refreshAll: true)
                       .SetCacheExpiration(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10));
   });

}, optional: false);   

builder.Services.Configure<DBSettings(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings:DBSettings"));
builder.Services.AddAzureAppConfiguration();


var app = builder.Build();
app.UseAzureAppConfiguration();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=home}/{action=privacy}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

**DBSettings.cs**

```
public class DBSettings
{
    public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
    public int DapperTimeout { get; set; }
}
```

**HomeController.cs**

```
public class AccountController : BaseController
{
    private readonly DBSettings settings;
    public AccountController(IOptions<DBSettings> options)
    {
        settings = options.Value;
    }    
    public async Task<IActionResult> AuthCallback()
    {
        var gg = settings.ConnectionString;
    }
}
```

The issue here is that the settings object is always null in the controller. However, It is not if I do it using the appsettings.json file.

**appsettings.json**

```
{
  "AppSettings": {
    "DBSettings": {
      "ConnectionString": "Server=tcp:aimoves-dev.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=AiMoves_Dev;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=itservices@aimoves.co.uk@aimoves-dev;Password=PtotheWorld@123;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;",
      "DapperTimeout": "200"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you inject IConfiguration and then look what kind of providers it includes in the debug? It should have an appsettings provider, environment provider and the azure app configuration provider.

Comment: @misha130 yes the IConfiguration has the AzureAppConfiguration provider in list of providers when I debug it. However, it has just a single value which is Appsettings:Sentinal and no other values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why Microsoft documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/enable-dynamic-configuration-aspnet-core?tabs=core5x) has not mentioned this in their documentation but we need to chain `Select()` on `Connect()` and specify the key and label filter for it to work.

**Program.cs**

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Configuration.AddAzureAppConfiguration(option =>
{
    option.Connect(builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("AppSettings:Settings"))
    .Select(keyFilter: KeyFilter.Any, builder.Environment.EnvironmentName)
    .ConfigureRefresh(refresh =>
    {
        refresh.Register("AppSettings:Sentinel", builder.Environment.EnvironmentName, refreshAll: true)
                           .SetCacheExpiration(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10));
    });

}, optional: false);
```